# how do i use HTML checkbox to insert 1 or 0 into mysql boolean

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a sign up sheet for an assignment but i am having difficulty as i have to allow for admin rights so i decide to create a column called administrator in my table as a boolean ie true or false. on my sign up sheet i wish to use a checkbox if its checked they are an administrator if not then they are not.

how can i make the check box = 1 or 0 to the mysql statment?

here is the code for sign up:

```
     <form method="POST" action="new-user 2.php">
             <td>Full Name</td><td>
             <input type="text" name="name"></td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
             <td>Email</td>
             <td> 
             <input type="text" name="email"></td> 
             </tr> 
             <tr>
            <td>UserName</td>
            <td> 
            <input type="text" name="user">
            </td> </tr> 
            <tr> 
            <td>Password</td>
            <td> 
            <input type="password" name="pass">
            </td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
            <td>Confirm Password </td>
            <td><input type="password" name="cpass">
            </td> 
            </tr> 
            </tr> 
            <tr>
            <td>Administrator </td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox" />
            </td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
            <td>
            <input id="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">
            </td> 
            </tr> 
        </form>
    </table>
    </fieldset>
    </div> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['cbox']))
{
    $administrator ='1';
}
else
{
    $administrator ='0';
}
?>
```

Thank you

**Update:**

The new user2.php code is as follows:

```
require_once('connection.php');
function NewUser() 
{ 
#$salt = 'sadfh9832asd34rf28asjvddap';
#$crypt = crypt ($salt .$password);

    $fullname = $_POST['name'];
    $userName = $_POST['user'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $administrator =$_POST['administrator'];
    #$password = crypt($_POST['pass']);
        $password = md5($_POST['pass']);
        echo "<hr>".$_POST['pass'] . "=[$password]<hr>";
    #$password = stripslashes($password); 
    #$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

    $query = "INSERT INTO `WebsiteUsers`(`fullname`, `userName`, `email`, `pass`, `administrator`)  VALUES ('$fullname','$userName','$email','$password', 'administrator')"; 
    $data = mysql_query ($query)or die(mysql_error()); 
        echo "<hr>$query<hr>";

    if($data) 
    { 
    echo "YOUR REGISTRATION IS COMPLETED..."; 
    } 
}

 function SignUp() 
 { 
     if(!empty($_POST['user'])) //checking the 'user' name which is from Sign-Up.html, is it empty or have some text
     { $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM WebsiteUsers WHERE userName = '$_POST[user]' 
     AND pass = '$_POST[pass]'") or die(mysql_error());

     if(!$row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error())) 
     { 
     newuser(); 
     } 
     else
     { 
     echo "SORRY...YOU ARE ALREADY A REGISTERED USER..."; }
     } 
} 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{ 
     SignUp(); 
} 

#header("location:index.html");
 ?>

<?php
$cookie_name = "cookieuser";
$cookie_value = $fullname;
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
?>
```

Comment: try to set value to your checkbox;

`<input type="checkbox" name="cbox" value="1" />`

Answer (score 0):

Give a value to the checkbox like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cbox" value="1" />
```

Then check if that value is assigned to the $_POST variable like this.

```
if($_POST['cbox'] == '1')
```

Complete code is listed below. I have done some modifications.

```
     <form method="POST" action="new-user 2.php">
             <td>Full Name</td><td>
             <input type="text" name="name"></td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
             <td>Email</td>
             <td> 
             <input type="text" name="email"></td> 
             </tr> 
             <tr>
            <td>UserName</td>
            <td> 
            <input type="text" name="user">
            </td> </tr> 
            <tr> 
            <td>Password</td>
            <td> 
            <input type="password" name="pass">
            </td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
            <td>Confirm Password </td>
            <td><input type="password" name="cpass">
            </td> 
            </tr> 
            </tr> 
            <tr>
            <td>Administrator </td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox" value="1" />
            </td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
            <td>
            <input id="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">
            </td> 
            </tr> 
        </form>
    </table>
    </fieldset>
    </div> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>


<?php
if(isset($_POST['cbox']))
{
    if($_POST['cbox'] == '1'){
        $administrator ='1';
    }else{
        $administrator ='0';
    }
}else
{
    $administrator ='0';
}
?>
```

Comment: The `isset` works as is. Give it a test and echo `$administrator`. This will not set `$administrator` if the box is unchecked, because it will be unset.

Comment: @chris85 Thank you for pointing that out. I just fixed and adding the edited code here.

Comment: sorry using that code i get the error 
Incorrect integer value: 'administrator' for column 'administrator' at row 1

Comment: @LeslieBraham Then remove '' from the value like this `$administrator = 1 ;` By using ' ' value becomes a string, If you remove it, it becomes an integer and will work on Boolean values in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Per your form elemenet, `<form method="POST" action="new-user 2.php">` this script is submitting to `new-user 2.php`. If this page is `new-user 2.php` then `$administrator` will be `1` or `0` (as a string).</s>

If this page is not `new-user 2.php` then this check:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['cbox']))
{
    $administrator ='1';
}
else
{
    $administrator ='0';
}
?>
```

will not run, because the PHP only executes on page load; it is not available once the page has loaded.

`$_POST['cbox']` is either going to have the value of `on` or not be set.

You can see all values being submitted by outputting the `POST` after the form is submitted with this, `print_r($_POST);`.

If this is `new-user 2.php` then please update your question to where the usage of `$administrator` can be seen.

Per your update code the issue is you are checking the wrong form element. Your form element is `cbox`, not `administrator`. You also are open to SQL injections with this code and are using the deprecated driver, `mysql_`. You should switch up to `mysqli` or `pdo`.

On to your code... Your `NewUser` function should be updated to:

```
function NewUser() 
{ 
#$salt = 'sadfh9832asd34rf28asjvddap';
#$crypt = crypt ($salt .$password);

    $fullname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $userName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $administrator = isset($_POST['cbox']) ? 1 : 0;
    #$password = crypt($_POST['pass']);
    $password = md5($_POST['pass']);
    echo "<hr>".$_POST['pass'] . "=[$password]<hr>";
    #$password = stripslashes($password); 
    #$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

    $query = "INSERT INTO `WebsiteUsers`(`fullname`, `userName`, `email`, `pass`, `administrator`)  VALUES ('$fullname','$userName','$email','$password', $administrator)"; 
    $data = mysql_query ($query)or die(mysql_error()); 
        echo "<hr>$query<hr>";

    if($data) 
    { 
    echo "YOUR REGISTRATION IS COMPLETED..."; 
    } 
}
```

Note the escaping and `$administrator = isset($_POST['cbox']) ? 1 : 0;`.

Comment: Please update your question, with updates. Don't post code in comments, hard to read.

Comment: using the code you have provided i am getting the error : Incorrect integer value: 'administrator' for column 'administrator' at row 1

Comment: Sorry, I corrected that 30 seconds after updating. I didn't notice at first your SQL had static value, not variable there. It is updated now.